# Need explanation for specific expression syntax that starts with an integer and a period

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

I have a `Table` statement that I don't understand:

```
scaledB = 
  Table[1. (# - A[[i, 1]])/A[[i, 2]] & /@ 
    B[[i]], {i, 1, Length[B]}];
```

Based on the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and Google, I know this `Table` statement is 
`Table[expr, {i, imin, imax} ]`. I don't understand the `1.` part in the expression. What does it do? I tried looking at the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PartsOfExpressions.html) for `expr` and Googling a variety of keywords, but since I don't know what it's called, I've been unable to find any helpful docs.

Comment: That means it is an approximate number (i.e. it’s `Head` is `Real`). It is causing the entire calculation to use approximate numbers which can often be faster and more memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks, @b3m2a1!

Comment: I am going to mark this question as *already has an answer* in a post that I hope you will find helpful.  If you feel that this is inappropriate please let me know.